# Spotify API 1.x get user session

Tags: spotify

Trying Spotify API 1.x.
My manifest

```
"Dependencies": {
      "api": "1.20.1",
      "views": "1.24.1"
  }
```

Having problem getting the current session with the new spotify API. [Session Docs](http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/preview/api/api-models-session.html)

After a while I got the user information with this:

```
require(['$api/models','$api/models#User','$api/models#Session'], function(models) {
    var user = models.User.fromURI('spotify:user:@');
    user.load('username', 'name').done(function(u) {
        userUid = u.identifier;
    });
});
```

But the Session doesn't have the load method (getting throw error) and when looking at the models.Session I can't se any values??? :(

Answer (score 1):

I changed on `manifest.json` API version to:

```
"api": "1.3.0"
```

Now I can get information from the session, for example my country:

```
var userCountry = models.session.country;
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the Spotify documentation a bit misleading regarding Sessions. There are a number of things I have found out by trial-and-error and Googling, rather than from the docs.

Like @Backer says, change the API version to 1.3.0 (or higher, when available). *Please note you have to restart Spotify for this to take effect*.

Then you can access the Session object like this (here, "session" *must* be lower case):

```
models.session.load('product','connection','device','user').done(function(s){
    console.log('sess:',s)
});
```

The User object will be part of this, but it won't be populated with properties unless you load them. Here is an example of retrieving a subset of properties from Session and User:

```
require([
'$api/models','$api/models#Session'
], function(models) {
app.user = {};
    models.session.load('product','connection','device','user').done(function(sess){
       sess.user.load('name', 'username', 'subscribed').done(function(user){
           app.user.name = user.name; // string
           app.user.username = user.username; // string
           app.user.subscribed = user.subscribed; // boolean
       });
       app.user.connection = sess.connection; // string
       app.user.country = sess.country; // string ISO-2
       app.user.device = sess.device; // string
       app.user.language = sess.language; // string ISO-2
       app.user.product = sess.product; // string

    });
});
```

The entire Session object:

```
Session
_done: 65535
_listening: true
_ob: Object
_obcount: 1
_requestArgs: Array[0]
_requestName: "session_event_wait"
capabilities: Object
connecting: false
connection: "wlan"
country: "SE"
developer: true
device: "desktop"
incognito: false
language: "en"
online: true
product: "open"
resolution: 1
streaming: "enabled"
testGroup: 000
user: User
    _done: 255
    currentUser: true
    identifier: "longcodehere"
    image: "http://profile-images.scdn.co/artists/default/anotherlongcodehere"
    images: Array[2]
    name: "My Name"
    subscribed: false
    uri: "spotify:user:@"
    username: "myusername"
    __proto__: c
    __proto__: c
```